# Посчитать в sql приведенное отличие

Tags: sql

[image: то что должно быть на выходе sql запроса , на примере excel , приведенное отличие здесь: поле dol2]
Т.е. по периоду 201632 считается разница доли в отличие от предыдущего периода и следующего периода ( они указаны) 
По сути мне нужно посчитать разницу долей между периодами  ( приведенное отличие ) 
Кто знает как это сделать в sql подскажите 
( Слышал , что делается через оконные функции sql )

Comment: Господи. Вставьте текстом или хотя скрином, а не фото...

Comment: А какой конкретно SQL, есть ли в вашем диалекте функции `lag()`/`lead()`. Собственно это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос, эти функции дают предыдущее/последующее значение при указанной в `over()` сортировке

Comment: Да на фотографии вообще Excel...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , использую SQ SQL ( белка)

Comment: Друзья, мне поставили задачу выполнить в sq sql приведенное отличие как в экселе ( на скрине)

Answer (score 0):

функции lag()/lead(). Собственно это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос, эти функции дают предыдущее/последующее значение при указанной в over() сортировке
Mike , спс